# How do you simplify verbose getElementById command

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing, getelementbyid

We have 26 functions to capture 26 alphabet button's action. Is it possible to simplify and combine 26 functions into one function by using some special trick? We gave the the first 3 examples as below.

```
function myFunctiona() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn_Q").value;
    document.getElementById("edit_area").focus();
    y=keyprocessing(x);
}
function myFunctionb() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn_W").value;
    document.getElementById("edit_area").focus();
    y=keyprocessing(x);
}

function myFunctionc() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn_E").value;
    document.getElementById("edit_area").focus();
    y=keyprocessing(x);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

BTW: I use function parameter, but stuck in some place. The code is as below.

```
<input type="button" id="myBtn_Q" onclick="myFunctionq('myBtn_Q')" value="q"> 
<input type="button" id="myBtn_W" onclick="myFunctionw('myBtn_W')" value="w">
<input type="button" id="myBtn_E" onclick="myFunctione('myBtn_E')" value="e">
function myFunctionTest(a){    
    var x = document.getElementById(a).value;
    alert(x);
    document.getElementById("edit_area").focus();
    y=keyprocessing(x);    
}
```

Comment: The trick is called function parameters.

Comment: Why are the click handlers still calling `myFunctionq`, `myFunctionw` etc instead of `myFunctionTest`?

Comment: You are not using the function named myFunctionTest()

Comment: Even better would be simply `onclick="myFunctionTest(this.value)"`, then you wouldn't even need to look up the element

Comment: Bergi,
Thank you so much. After changing them into myFunctionTest, it works.
Thank you everyone!

Comment: Phil, you are totally correct. The code is more succinct after using onclick="myFunctionTest(this.value)". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="alphabet-button" value="a"/>   


 document.getElementById('alphabet-button').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   var x = e.target.value;
   alert(x);
   document.getElementById("edit_area").focus();
   y=keyprocessing(x);  
 });
```

Comment: Hayden, this is wonderful. However, I need to arrange these buttons into 3 lines by using <br> tag like they arranged in physical keyboard. So, it seems Phil's method is better one. Thank you very much!